# How to add user-script like tamparmonky on chrome extention

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Hello i am trying to create a chrome extension. It like tampermonky. It add some user script. But the problem is some variable show undefined, But when i use the same script on tampermonky there is no error.
My extension manifest.json is

```
{
    "name": "SayHello",
    "description": "It will say hello when a page finishied load.",
    "version": "0.4",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>",
        "storage"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "exclude_globs":[],
            "include_globs":["*"],
            "matches": [
                "http://www.amazon.com/*",
                "https://www.amazon.com/*"
            ],
            "js": ["email.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ], 
    "converted_from_user_script": true,
    "manifest_version":2
}
```

and email.js is.

```
P.when("jQuery","ready").execute(function(t){
    var i="http://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/A3U7NCDBQ95EJM/customer_email";
    t.get(i,function(t){
        var o=t.data.email;
        console.log('o:'+o);
    });
    return t;
});
```

error massage is `Uncaught ReferenceError: P is not defined`

Comment: can you clean that code plz? ;)

Comment: this is not enough code. We need to see where your `P` is created.

Comment: This `P` is created in a JavaScript code in www.amazon.com website. You can see by following step. Go to amazon.com open console and run the JavaScript code. it will work and this code run only console and tampermonky.

Comment: I want to run this code by a chrome extension.